# Is it possible in CSS to make a div expand (on zoom) until it hits window (not document) size and then stop expanding?

Tags: html, css

I would like to use CSS only to make a div that will expand when the user zooms until it reaches the window size and for it not to react to zoom anymore after that. Is this possible?

Example:

1. Div starts at `10em` (equivalent to `160px` on normal desktop with no zoom)
2. User starts pressing `ctrl +` to make it zoom (and increasing the value of an `em`)
3. When the div hits window size (for example `1600px`) it stops reacting to the change in `em` size. **The width of the window size would *not* be known beforehand (so 1600px could not be set as the max-width)**

Comment: I don't think with pure css it will be possible.. but I am eagerly waiting for an answer..

Comment: I don't think it is possible only with css.Although with javascript or jquery it is possible.If you want solution with this, then i can help you

Comment: @Roshanjha Thanks but I can do it with JS, I only wanted a cleaner CSS-only solution if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Before some big gun gives a solution, this is not possible IMHO...

I doubt there is any way in pure CSS to achieve this as you will be needing some `jQuery` or `JS` to detect the width....

My first thought was for media queries but even  they can't be used for this dynamic function...as we restrict the width through them!

Another reason is that, to detect <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, you *will* be needing `jQuery` to detect the `keypress` and apply desired functionality in that event!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you structure your html, you can use width percentages to have a an element expand to the full width of the window without js, but you would require js to detect keyboard input in order to trigger your css.

you can also tie css transitions to the width / height styles to animate the zoom.

but if you are using number values in your css you wuld need js to pull those values for you.

here is fiddle on a simple way to do the zoom with css just by adding and removing a css class... but unfortunatly you need some js to add and remove the class...

```
<div class="window">
    <div>
        <div class="zoomBox">
            <span class="expand">+</span>&nbsp;<span>-</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/asmkdLuw/5/)